# What is this part called?

Tags: components

Kind of a random question, but what are the blue wire-clamp-things in the image below called?

[image: Motor Controller Board]

I see those everywhere, and I think they'd be awesome to have in a grab bag...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are terminal blocks.

More specifically those look like eurostyle terminal blocks.

Comment: Circle takes the square!

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to buy like 50 of those to keep around!

Comment: @KevinSoviero: Nah, you want the lever clamp ones instead.

Comment: @Ignacio Why do you prefer lever clamp ones over the screw-in model?

Comment: @us2012: Because you don't have to reach for the screwdriver.

Answer (score 7):

Those parts are a type of terminal connector - typically called a screw down or clamping terminal block. There are various types including PC-mount, 90 degree edge mount, and even surface mount. They also come with various numbers of positions (number of clamping wire terminals).

They make an excellent was of connecting larger gauge wire (such as for a motor, battery, speaker, etc) to a PCB board, but they introduce noise, so they are not well suited for sensitive lines such as data transmission.

Here are some at a site call [all-electronics.com](http://www.allelectronics.com/). They are relatively cheap.

[2 Position PCB Terminal - Green](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/TER-202/2-POSITION-PCB-TERMINAL-BLOCK/1.html)

[2 Position PCB Terminal - Blue](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/TER-502/2-POSITION-PC-MOUNT-TERMINAL-STRIP/1.html)

[2 and 3 Position Interlocking Terminal - Blue](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/TER-605/2-3-POSITION-TERMINAL-STRIP/1.html)

[4 Position Pluggable Terminal](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/TER-104/4-POSITION-PLUGGABLE-TERMINAL-STRIP-AND-HEADER/1.html)

Comment: Just for completeness, what sort of connector would introduce less noise and be good for data transmission?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the frequency and purpose of the signal. That would be best answered as an independent question.